# Can we use aliased field to use in ORDER BY clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Can we use *aliased* field name in `ORDER BY` clause?

For example:

```
SELECT id, name AS firstname
FROM users
ORDER BY firstname
```

Is it possible? When I tried this it errored out.

Comment: There should not be any error because its correct. And what error is there ?

Comment: "Thanks All!" .Perhaps I had mistaken. I should have to research more .It's working now.

Comment: This exact situation (`SELECT some_column as "Some Column"`) caused me to **finally** understand the significance of backticks around column names. If you were to `ORDER BY "Some Column"`, the results aren't correctly sorted, but with backticks instead of double quotes, they are. I don't know what would be the purpose of `ORDER`ing by a literal string, but that appears to be how MySQL interprets it when double-quoted.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a
>   different name. You can use the alias in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING
>   clauses to refer to the column.

Check [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/problems-with-alias.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try with this one, I have added back-ticks to column name and table Because name is the reserved word :

```
SELECT `id`, `name` AS firstname
FROM `users`
ORDER BY firstname
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can certainly use column aliases in your "order by" clause.

You can verify it works with the built-in mySql "user" table:

```
 select User as name,Host from user order by name;
```

If it "errored out", then something *else* must have been wrong with your query.  Please cut/paste the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

In order to tell of you can use aliases in certain clauses, check the order in which SQL procceses the the queries and it is as follows:
-from
-where
-group by
-having
-order by

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use alias in GROUP BY Clause in MS SQL SERVER

Comment: Exactly, it gives me this error: Unknown column 'table_name.aliased_name' in 'order clause':